# Variable transformation in a ANOVA and multivariate analyses

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, normality-assumption

I want to run an ANOVA, and the multiple correlation and regression analyses. Some of my variables to be included in these analyses are normally distributed and some are not. I log transformed the not normally distributed variables which helped to normalize them. My question is whether I can use both the log transformed and not transformed variables in the same analysis? For example, can I have 2 variables transformed and 3 not transformed and use them all in the multiple regression; can I have the dependent variable transformed and the independent variable not transformed, and use it in ANOVA? Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems you are having in mind the idea to ascertain multiple correlation in place of multivariate correlation. The latter term is not  included in statistics at least. Please correct the body of question

Comment: Further, it does not seem relevant to determine that a variable is normally distributed or not. ANOVA methodology invokes the least-square theory.

Comment: It is not clear which transformation you have in mind. Is it standard score ?

Comment: It is log transformation.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, one of the assumptions of ANOVA is that the variables should be normally distributed. Why would invoking the least-square theory invalidate this assumption?

Comment: @subhash c. davar: It is in turn incorrect to say "multivariate correlation" is not included in statistics. Very likely it is not what Katie wishes to do, but that's a different detail.

Comment: There is no problem in principle in mixing transformed and untransformed variables in an analysis. It's common to find that you are better transforming the response variable, but that the predictors should stay as they are. It may be that you are overvaluing the assumption of normality here, but that's difficult to say without knowing much more about your data and precisely what you are doing.